# iOS make object come back up after moving down

Tags: ios, iphone, collision, motion

I have an object that falls from the top of the screen however i want it to come back up after the bottom of the object reaches the bottom of the screen. This is my code at the moment. I tried adding another image view to trigger the up motion by collision. The timer is in `ViewDidLoad`

```
hammer.center = CGPointMake(hammer.center.x, hammer.center.y + 12);

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(hammer.frame, floor.frame)) {
        hammer.center = CGPointMake(hammer.center.x , hammer.center.y -50);
}
```

Comment: actually your question is not completed. will you explain what is your exact problem.

Comment: UIKitDynamics is probably something you should look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wont see it animate, maybe try animating the view instead of moving it instantly.

Place this in viewDidAppear to see it after the view has come on the screen.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                 animations:^{
                   hammer.center = CGPointMake(hammer.center.x, hammer.center.y + 12);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                                    animations:^{
                                      if (CGRectIntersectsRect(hammer.frame, floor.frame)) {
                                        hammer.center = CGPointMake(hammer.center.x , hammer.center.y -50);
                                      }
                                    }];
                 }];
```